# Appscript: how to repeat a while loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, while-loop

This is my while loop as it stands at the moment:

```
function rowcount()
{ 
  var token = getAccessToken();
  var module = "sHistory";
  var rows = 0;
  var go = true;
  var i = 1;
  var data;
  
   
   while (go) {
     //Utilities.sleep(10000)
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false;
    };
    if ((i%10) == 0) {
       go = false; 
    }
    rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
      i++;
   
      Logger.log("rowcount " + rows)
      }
      return rows
   }
```

My question is how do I use a for loop to repeat the while loop 93 times with a timer of 10 seconds per passing?

Can you demonstrate by giving a sample of for loop code? I have been sitting on this for days, I have tried a for loop, but I think I am doing it wrong, please assist, I created a new function that I am trying to repeat the while function.

```
function repeatloop()
{
  for(i=rowcount(); i <= 10; i++)
      {
        Utilities.sleep(10000)
        Logger.log(i)
        i++
      }
}
```

I just need the above sorted out for my script to be completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` should be initialized to `0`. Call `i++` only once.

```
function repeatloop() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    console.log(i);
    console.log(rowcount());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is working

Comment: Oh yes! one last thing, How do I make it so that for every repeat it adds a number on to the next passing, so if the first passing ends with 2000 how to make it so that it adds the last count every time until it stops?

Comment: @MrJnrDev Kindly ask a new question with more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval`.

Something like this:

```
function repeatLoop() {
  let i = 0;
  if (typeof repeatLoop.prototype.counter === 'undefined') {
    repeatLoop.prototype.counter = 0;
  }
  const intervalInstance = setInterval(() => {
    if (i > 10) {
      clearInterval(intervalInstance);
    } else {
      console.log(repeatLoop.prototype.counter);
      i++;
      repeatLoop.prototype.counter++;
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```